# how to load MS-ASL dataset and avoid error 429, videos are on youtube

Tags: python, youtube

I am trying to load the MS-ASL dataset to work on a project. The issue is that all of the videos are on youtube and dont come with the dataset. I am currently trying to download all of them. The issue I am having is that I keep running into the 429 error of too many requests. I am putting a sleep in my code to avoid it, but recently after a day of it working the error popped up again. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to work with this dataset or get it. Calling the video when training or testing doesnt seem reasonable, since I would have to wait at least 30 seconds between each sample so that I dont trigger the error it seems like. Please correct me if I am wrong. Here is my code, in case there is something I can do to avoid it.

```
def downLoadVideo(i,place,count,x):
try:
    try:
        time.sleep(30)
        yt = YouTube(i)
        mp4_files = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4")
        mp4_369p_files = mp4_files.get_by_resolution("360p")
        word.append(MSASL_test["clean_text"][place])
        mp4_369p_files.download("./train",MSASL_test["clean_text"][place].replace(" ","")+str(count))
        MSASL_test["file"][x]="./train/"+MSASL_test["clean_text"][place].replace(" ","")+str(count)
        count=count+1
        print(str(count)+" "+MSASL_test["clean_text"][place])
        MSASL_test.to_csv('./train/data.csv', index=False)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
        print(e)
        print(type(e))
        place,count =downLoadVideo(i,place,count)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
place=place+1
return place,count

for x in range(len(MSASL_test["url"])):
   i=MSASL_test["url"][x]
   place,count=downLoadVideo(i,place,count,x)
```

[link to colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qzL5DfZ3Zu0sVhKyUmbuWP1FJmFuuyDh?usp=sharing)

So I was looking more into the dataset and noticedthat often a words are linked to the same video. I havent implemented this, but maybe if you just get the unique video links and download them it may help avoid the error.

Comment: Can you reconsider add one more `sleep` after `mp4_files = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4")`? - that might help, otherwise, try to download the data/videos and store them in a separate location, then, try again the code, but, don't re-download the already obtained data.

Comment: yeah I am currently using colab to do it in sections. wouldnt adding the extra sleep between the steps be the same as just increasing the time in the first step? @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes

Comment: Nikita, if you provide a google colab notebook sample, I could give it a try.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I mean it works, I was just wondering if someone had a better way or maybe somewhere it exsisted with the videos already downloaded. Here is the link incase there is something to fix. The only issue I have is colab kicking me off with this. I dont think it runs long enough for the error to pop up. I added the link  at the end of my question.

Comment: can you make the collab sample public, please?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes should be public now

Comment: thank you. What is the content of `/Thesis/train/data.csv`?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes it is the train dataset of the MS-ASL dataset. Except for instead of json, I changed it to csv